# C - Creating a struct in a source file

Tags: c, function, struct, header

I am hanging around for the last 6 hours trying to get this damn problem solved. First I'm a complete newbie in c programming, so don't expect too much from me please..
I need to write a programm, that creates an Integer Array within a struct. So I wrote a header and made another source file named "intarray.c" besides the main, because I have to do so. I included everything etc etc and now I need a function, that gets an argument "int n", that is used to create the int array a[n] inside of the struct. But I can't get this to work.. Sorry for my bad explanation, but I don't know what the heck I'm doing here. I also tried working with pointers, but that confused me and I'm not sure if they are necessary.

My header looks like that:

```
#ifndef INTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define INTARRAY_H_INCLUDED

struct IntArray
{
    int length;
    int numbers[];
};
void create(int);
void destruct();
void read(int);
void write(int, int);

#endif // INTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
```

and my function looks like that:

```
create(int n)
{
    struct IntArray arr;
    arr.length = n;
    arr.numbers[n];
}
```

But now I can't use the structure in other functions, e.g. if I want to write in the array on a specific position. How can I solve this?
And sry for dumb questions.

Comment: This snippet does not even compile. Read about flexible array members and dynamic memory allocation. Your function prototypes are wrong, too. In short: too many errors in alomost no code shown. Recap your course material or get a good C book and ask your tutor for advice.

Comment: `struct IntArray *create(int n){ struct IntArray *arr = calloc(1, sizeof(*arr) + n * sizeof(int)); if(arr){ arr.length = n; } return arr; }`

Comment: If a struct has a flexible array member, it has to be allocated using `malloc()` so you can add the size of the array that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically allocate memory:

```
struct IntArray
{
    int length;
    int * numbers;
};

struct IntArray * create(int len) {
    struct IntArray * ret = malloc(sizeof(struct IntArray));
    ret->length = len;
    ret->numbers = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with a *flexible array member* (FAM), you need to explicitly allocate the memory for the structure and the array as a single allocation, as illustrated by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43856777/c-creating-a-struct-in-a-source-file#comment74749561_43856777).

You also need to write compilable code:

```
struct IntArray *create(int n)
{
    struct IntArray *result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + n * sizeof(result->numbers[0]));
    if (result != NULL)
        result->length = n;
    return result;
}
```

If you're on a 64-bit system, the size of the basic structure is probably 8 bytes, not the 4 you'd normally expect, because the pointer needs to be aligned on an 8-byte boundary so the compiler adds 4 bytes of padding.  On a 32-bit system, the size would be 4 because the size of the flexible array member is not included in the size of the structure.